# OpenWRT: How to create interface for pptpd virtual PPP interfaces?

Tags: networking, network-interface, vpn, openwrt, pptp

In OpenWrt, I can setup almost any kind of interface in `/etc/config/network`. But I haven't found a way to create an interface for the PPP "virtual interfaces" created by the pptpd daemon (PPtP Server).

Theses interfaces are usually called `ppp0`, `ppp1` etc., and I'd like to access all of them by a single interface name and create a separate firewall zone for them.

I can manually add `ppp1` to the already existing LAN bridge, but when I create a bridge with static address and containing only the PPP interfaces, my router becomes inaccessible after reboot (and the logfiles are held in RAM, so no way to read what's going on there).

Clarification: I'm not trying to set up interfaces for PPtP *client* (that works fine even through LuCi), but for a PPtP *server*.

Comment: To match all interfaces of a type, use the plus sign such as ppp+.(any iptables rule which is set for interface ppp+ will match ppp0, ppp1, ppp2 etc.)

Comment: @SouravGhosh You're talking about iptables, but I'm talking about network interfaces configuration (what's displayed in Luci admin/network/network page).